# Can Mathematica be used to create an Artistic 3D extrusion from a 2D image and wrap a line pattern around it?

Tags: image-processing, generative-art

So here's somewhat of the general goal first:  Here's an example of image-based line patterns
[Here is an example of an artists work in creating imagery using only lines](https://www.instagram.com/p/BagxgLEHLuk/)
bent as though distorted by an actual 3D form.

Seemed to me that something like this could be accomplished in Mathematica using a 2D image and a line pattern.

Processing the 2D image in such a way as to maintain the edges then use some of the original pixel luminance to extrude a depth map.   Then use this new 3D form to deform the line pattern and create this artistic effect.

Here's an image to begin with:[link](https://www.liveenhanced.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Beauty-Of-Bears-Ears-National-Monument.jpg)

Here's some code that may (or may not) get the creative juices flowing. 
[converting Images](https://blog.wolfram.com/2008/12/01/the-incredible-convenience-of-mathematica-image-processing/)

In my application, I will need to use a second image to warp over the new 3D form because the pattern effect is going to be very different than this example image.

Here is an example of a grayscale image pattern to be used on this type of work.  [image: Grayscale patterned image]

The end result/goal is a warped 3D pattern only which shows the details of the previous image clearly (similar to the artistic example).

Comment: Depth map is also easily done via https://resources.wolframcloud.com/NeuralNetRepository/resources/Single-Image-Depth-Perception-Net-Trained-on-NYU-Depth-V2-and-Depth-in-the-Wild-Data

Comment: and this can be done for the edge details:  Manipulate[EdgeDetect[image, r, t], {{r, 2, "radius"}, 1, 10}, 
    {{t, 0.1, "threshold"}, 0, 0.5}]

Comment: I do need to be able to convolve an image of lines because although the example image is nice, the use case is different and thus the line pattern would have to be different.

Comment: You should also give `ImageRestyle` a shot. If it has enough time I think it could do a really nice job of this.

Comment: Can you give a few examples of "any grayscale image pattern provided"? I think that is where the disconnect between these answers and your hoped-for solution lies.

Comment: Good point!  I'll post one in the question Carl,  thanks!

Comment: It's still 100% clear to me what you're looking for. Is something like this what you're after? https://i.stack.imgur.com/njaZG.jpg

Comment: The end result/goal is a warped 3D pattern only which shows the details of the previous image clearly (similar to the artistic example).  The pattern should be able to be plotted as a 3D file and rotated it should only contain the pattern and not a background in the 3D file so it can be placed and rotated.  The pattern should not be tiled.

Comment: I feel a little bit like your requirements have either evolved to not fit the answers or don't match what's in your question. Please consider adding more detailed requirements to your question, because it is quite frustrating to spend a lot of time to write an answer and be told it doesn't match uncommunicated requirements.

Comment: It is not my goal to move the finish line, but I have answered any and all questions.  If there is something that is not clear please ask for clarification. From what I can see your answer is good except did not provide the ability to change the pattern as was listed in the question.  I have added a pattern as you have requested.  Let me know if you need anything else, and I'll happily help with whatever is needed.

Answer (score 18):

Other approach using NetModel:

```
net = NetModel[
   "Single-Image Depth Perception Net Trained on NYU Depth V2 and \
Depth in the Wild Data"];
```

[image]

Create depthMap and build an interpolation function:

```
depthMap = net[image];    
depthFunc = 
  Interpolation[
   Flatten[MapIndexed[{#2, #1} &, -Reverse@depthMap, {2}], 1]];
```

Apply depthFunc to line segments and plot it:

```
lines = Table[{j, i, 7 depthFunc[i, j]}, {i, 1, 240, 4}, {j, 1, 320, 
3}];

lineart3d = 
 Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[2], 
   GeometricTransformation[Line[lines], 
    RotationTransform[-Pi/12, {1, 0, 0}]]}, ViewPoint -> Top, 
  ViewProjection -> "Orthographic", Boxed -> False, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

You can rasterize if you want a 2d image:

```
Rasterize[lineart3d, ImageResolution -> 300]
```

[image]

Comment: +1 Nice work halmir!  I do need to change the type of line pattern from the example image, so if you can edit your answer to allow for that we may just have a winner!

Comment: You could modify magnifying value and allow negative.

Comment: Very nice given the complexity of the original image.

Answer (score 16):

Here's my attempt, which uses the neural net Carl Lange referred to, plots mesh lines with `ListPlot3D`, and finds a 'nice' view point to see the lines.

```
net = NetModel["Single-Image Depth Perception Net Trained on NYU Depth V2 and Depth in the Wild Data"];
img = Import["https://www.liveenhanced.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Beauty-Of-Bears-Ears-National-Monument.jpg"];
{x, y} = ImageDimensions[img];

height = 1 - Rescale[ArrayResample[net[img], Round[{x, y}/4]]];

meshlines = ListPlot3D[
  400 Reverse[height], 
  Mesh -> 100, MeshFunctions -> {#2 &}, 
  DataRange -> {{0, x}, {0, y}}, PlotStyle -> None
];

mr = DiscretizeGraphics[meshlines, 
  MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}, PlotTheme -> "Lines"];

M = MomentOfInertia[Point[MeshCoordinates[mr]]];

{v1, v2} = Rest[Eigenvectors[M]];

Show[mr, ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1}, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 10, 10} Normalize[Cross[v1, v2]]]
```

[image]

It might be possible to accentuate the detail better by finding a suitable power to raise `height` to, e.g. `height^2`, etc.

---

Here's a way to project into 2D, rather than adjusting the `ViewPoint` in 3D:

```
MeshRegion[
  -PrincipalComponents[MeshCoordinates[mr]][[All, 1 ;; 2]], 
  MeshCells[mr, 1], 
  PlotTheme -> "Lines", MeshCellStyle -> {1 -> Black}
]
```

[image]

---

Here's a way to add some smooth edge lines. There's room for improvement here -- both in the implementation and output -- and the high degree splines take some time to render.

The idea is to edge detect, break up branch points to get a collection of path curves, approximate each path with a smooth curve, then map into 3D.

```
boundary = Thinning[EdgeDetect[im, 10]];

brokenboundary = ImageMultiply[boundary, ColorNegate[MorphologicalBranchPoints[boundary]]];

ones = Position[Reverse[Transpose[ImageData[brokenboundary]], {2}], 1];

g = NearestNeighborGraph[ones, {All, 1.5}];

comps = WeaklyConnectedGraphComponents[g];

paths = FindHamiltonianPath /@ comps;

hmap = ListInterpolation[400 Reverse[Transpose[height], {2}], {{0, x}, {0, y}}];
paths3d = Apply[{##, hmap[##]} &, paths, {2}];

Show[
  mr, 
  Graphics3D[{AbsoluteThickness[1], BSplineCurve[#, SplineDegree -> Length[#] - 1] & /@ paths3d}], 
  ViewVertical -> {0, 0, -1}, 
  ViewPoint -> {0, 10, 10} Normalize[Cross[v1, v2]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really nice, great work!

Comment: @CarlLange Thanks!

Comment: +1 Nice work Chip!  In my case, I do need to use an image for the pattern of lines since that will need to be different.  Possibly adding EdgeDetect to gain a more defined shape definition like the example image.

Comment: @RHall do you mean have some edge lines in addition to the horizontal ones?

Comment: Yes, I have a large number of pattern images that I would use instead of the example provided.

Comment: @RHall see my latest edit.

Answer (score 14):

We can get some of the way there by using `ListContourPlot`.

[image]

Now we grab a neural network to get the depth map for us:

```
net = NetModel[
  "Single-Image Depth Perception Net Trained on NYU Depth V2 and Depth in the Wild Data"]
```

Now we can see our depth map:

[image]

Great. Let's put that in a list, after a little bit of cajoling (`Blur`ring, `ImageAdjust`ing so it's all between 0 and 1)

```
depth = ImageData@Blur@ImageAdjust@Image@net[i]
```

Now we can try and `ListContourPlot` it:

```
ListContourPlot[Reverse@depth, Contours -> 25, 
 ColorFunction -> (White &), Axes -> None, Frame -> None, 
 AspectRatio -> ImageAspectRatio@i]
```

[image]

Or, with the image you linked to:

[image]

Other options I thought about but didn't execute on:

- convolving an image of lines with the depth map
- converting the depthmap to a weighted graph and using `FindShortestPath` (I still like this one, but I think the output would be pretty similar to this attempt)
- There's always good old `ImageRestyle`, which if given enough time might do a really nice job of this...

Comment: I like this!  I do need to be able to convolve an image of lines though because although the example image is nice, the use case is different and thus the line pattern would have to be different.

Answer (score 12):

ImageRestyle is an obvious thing to try:

```
img = Import["https://www.liveenhanced.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Beauty-Of-Bears-Ears-National-Monument.jpg"];
imgBW = ColorConvert[img, "Grayscale"];
imgLines = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/bR9kS.png"];
ColorConvert[ImageRestyle[imgBW, imgLines], "Grayscale"]
```

[image]

If you are willing to wait a while, ImageRestyle has options:

```
resty = ImageRestyle[imgBW, imgLines, PerformanceGoal -> "Quality"]; 
ColorConvert[resty, "Grayscale"]
```

[image]

Comment: Good attempt Bill, Trying this method doesn't provide the distorted pattern only.  Seems some of the first image is left to show through the effect. The line pattern should end up as a single distorted 3D object.